# SavedPreferences does not save

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onpause

I am playing around a bit with android's SharedPreferences.

See my code:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
         prefs.edit().putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i));
         System.out.println(meds.get(i));
         String str = prefs.getString("0", "");
         System.out.println(str);
         System.out.println(i);


    }


        prefs.edit().commit();




  }
```

Now I get all the prints except for that which is supposed to print str.
I take it nothing is saved.

But why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `prefs.edit()` returns a new editor on the shared prefernces.
If you do `prefs.edit().commit();` the commit operates on a **new** editor object. You have to store a reference to the editor like that:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
        editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i));
        System.out.println(meds.get(i));
        String str = prefs.getString("0", "");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

**Otherwise nothing is saved.**

Comment: Sounds reasonable, however I have to get to work (this is hobby) and cannot test it before that. Will reply again in 12 hours or so

Comment: Just store the reference of the editor in a variable `SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();` and use the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Commit after putting a String in `Preferences`

### Corrected Code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
    "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
    editor.putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i));
    System.out.println(meds.get(i));
    String str = prefs.getString("0", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(i);
}

editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

commit after putting.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
         prefs.edit().putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i)).commit();
         System.out.println(meds.get(i));
         String str = prefs.getString("0", "");
         System.out.println(str);
         System.out.println(i);


    }
```

Comment: Does not change anything. And, in any case, there is only ONE object in a list so should not I be able to reach it?

Answer (score -1):

try like this,

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         for (int i = 0; i<meds.size(); i++){
         prefs.edit().putString(String.valueOf(i), meds.get(i));
         System.out.println(meds.get(i));

         System.out.println(str);
         System.out.println(i);


    }


        prefs.edit().commit();


 String str = prefs.getString("0", "");

  }
```

Comment: Your ansewer is not correct. The problem is that prefs.edit() creates everytime a new editor object.